# Solutions of a special system of diophantine equations?

Tags: nt.number-theory

How many nonnegative integer solutions of the following diophantine equations? And how to find them?
   \begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=r\\
x_1+2x_2+\cdots+nx_n=n\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation} 
where $1\leq r\leq n;r,n\in Z^+.$

I will appreciate  it for any advices and suggestions!
 Thank you very much!

Comment: @Matt Solutions are only required to be non-negative, so I don't see even why the LHS of the first equation has to be at least $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions correspond to partitions of $n$ into $r$ parts, and $x_i$ is the number of times that part $i$ is used.  A recurrence is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts), and you can use a similar recursion to enumerate them.

Comment: @Pratt  Thanks a lot. Actually, it is equivalent to the following equations:   \begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-r+1}=r\\
x_1+2x_2+\cdots+(n-r+1)x_{n-r+1}=n\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation} 
where $1\leq r\leq n;r,n\in Z^+.$

Comment: There are some relations between patial Bell Polynomial and this problems.  The number of  solutions  is the  number of monomials in Bell polynomial  $B_{n,r}(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_{n-r+1})$.

Comment: @Pratt. The recurrence just gives the number of solutions. My question is how to find these solutions.

Comment: Condition on $x_n$, the number of times that part $n$ appears.